# Insert sorted in priority queue

Tags: c, priority-queue

I've created a priority queue for messages in a mailbox based on their importance (1 - urgent, 0 - usual) and in my enqueue function I'd like to be able to insert priority 0 messages alphabetically sorted by their destination. I can provide the full code if needed but this is the function where I'm facing the issue:

```
void enqueue(char *dest, char *cont, int pr) //destination, content, priority
{
    struct node* msg = newNode(dest, cont, pr);
    if(head == NULL && tail == NULL)
    {
        head = msg;
        tail = msg;
    }
    else
    {
        if(msg->priority == 1)
        {
            temp = head;
            head = msg;
            msg->next = temp;
            return;
        }
        if(msg->priority == 0)
        {
            tail->next = msg;
            tail = msg;
        }

        temp = head;
        while(temp->next != NULL)
        {
            if(msg->priority > temp->next->priority)
            {
                struct node* newy;
                newy = temp->next;
                temp->next = msg;
                msg->next = newy;
            }
            /*else if(msg->priority == 0 && temp->next->priority == 0)
            {
                if(strcmp(msg->destination, temp->next->destination) > 0)
                {
                    struct node* newy;
                    newy = msg;
                    msg = temp->next;
                    temp->next = newy;
                }
            }*/
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
}
```

I've commented out one of my attempts to do this, but that didn't work. Also, when I'm displaying my queue, is it possible to, instead of printing the current layout of the elements inside the queue, print them in alphabetical order by destination for instance (both urgent and usual messages)? Thanks!

```
void display()
{
    temp = head;
    while(temp != NULL) 
    { 
        printf("Destination = |%s| | Content = |%s| | Priority = |%d|\n",temp->destination, temp->content, temp->priority);  
        temp = temp->next; 
    } 

}
```

Comment: Well, obviously a priority queue sorts primarily on priority, but I see no reason why you couldn't - for items that share a specific priority level - augment the comparison to make one item appear before another based on e.g. destination. What's the special significance of priority zero in your commented-out code?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Well I only want the priority 0 messages to be sorted, for e.g:
```enqueue("ab", "msg1", 1); enqueue("zy", "msg2", 1); enqueue("b", "usual1", 0); enqueue("a", "usual2", 0); enqueue("z", "usual3", 0);```
should insert in the queue: ```zy -> ab -> a-> b -> z```

Comment: FWIW, I would use a [heap data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) for this with a general compare function, which compares two items based on priorities, obviously, and then, only if those match, compares based on destination. That way there's nothing special in the code about priority level zero.